# Gaining access to content inserted dynamically with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the fragment of code inserted with ajax:

```
<form>
    <label for = "task-name">Name</label>
    <input type = "text" id = "task-name" />

    <label for = "task-description">Description</label>
    <input type = "text" id = "task-description" />

    <input type = "hidden" id = "task-col" />
    <input type = "hidden" id = "task-row" />

    <input type = "submit" id = "add-task" onclick="return false" value="Add" />

</form>
```

This is the JS code which insert the previous element in the DOM:

```
$('html').on('click', '.task-pop', function(){
    var pos = $(this).parent().parent().attr('class').split("-");
    ajaxObj = getXmlHttpObject();
    ajaxObj.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxObj.readyState == 4 && ajaxObj.status == 200){
            $('#pop-hold').html(ajaxObj.responseText);
            $('#task-col').val(pos[0]);
            $('#task-row').val(pos[1]);
        }
    };
    ajaxObj.open("GET","resources/component/newTask.jsp");
    ajaxObj.send(null);

    $('#pop-blk').css('display','block');
    $('#pop').show("fast");
});
```

As you can see I'm trying to add some values to the hidden inputs `#task-row` and `#task-col` from the content added dynamically.

The page is properly displayed and no error is thrown but those two fields are never accessed. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
$('#pop-hold').html(ajaxObj.responseText);
$('#task-col').val(pos[0]);
$('#task-row').val(pos[1]);
```

with

```
var html = $(ajaxObj.responseText);
html.find('#task-col').val(pos[0]);
html.find('#task-row').val(pos[1]);
$('#pop-hold').html('').append(html);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use **jQuery** ajax(), would be much easier for you to handle the whole Ajax thing :

```
$('html').on('click', '.task-pop', function(){
    var pos = $(this).parent().parent().attr('class').split("-");

    $.ajax({
      url: 'resources/component/newTask.jsp',
      type: 'GET', // Default value is GET but I included it for you
      success: function(data) {
            $('#pop-hold').empty().append(data);
            $('#task-col').val(pos[0]);
            $('#task-row').val(pos[1]);
      }
    });

    $('#pop-blk').css('display','block');
    $('#pop').show("fast");
});
```

Just a part of the solution, hope it will help ^^

Comment: Thank you! Useful but I'm trying to stick to plain JS as much as possible :)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the inputs are hidden don't prevent you from setting their value with `val()`.
When you call the val function like this `$('#task-col').val(pos[0]);`, make sure that:

- The #task-col element exists
- pos[0] is not undefined (you can test by replacing `pos[0]` with `"test"`)
- you are actually executing this line (you can test by putting an `altet("test")` the line before)

And when you use jQuery, don't mess around with the getXmlHttpObject as @Ethenyl said. Use [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) instead.